# How to store the data dynamically in linked list in C?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to store the values in the linked list dynamically.

I want the user to input the size of the linked List. Then based on the input I want to allocate the memory (i.e if Input : 3 then three nodes should be created).

If memory is allocated for nodes then I store the `head` node  in a `temp`.

After that I want to store the data in list untill list comes to the end

**The algorithm which I used is following**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node                                                           
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};


// Printing the list
void printList(struct node *ptr)
{
    int i = 1;
    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("\n Value in Node %d : %d",i ,ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
        i++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    struct node *head;
    struct node *temp;
    printf("\n Enter the size of linkedList : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    head = malloc(sizeof(struct node) * n);

    // Storing head in temp
    temp = head;
    int i = 1; // Keep track on the position of the list
    while(temp != NULL) // Untill temp get to end of the list
    {
        printf("\n Enter the value in node %d : ", i);
        scanf("%d",&temp->data);
        temp = temp->next; // Assinging next list address
    }
    printList(head);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand **why it printing only one value** when I'm executing it.

**I don't know how wrong I was?**

**OUTPUT : **

`$ clang dynamicList.c -o a`

`$ ./a`

`Enter the size of linkedList : 10`

`Enter the value in node 1 : 9`

`Value in Node 1 : 9`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This call of malloc

```
head = malloc(sizeof(struct node) * n);
```

allocates an uninitialized memory.

Thus this statement in the while loop

```
temp = temp->next;
```

assigns an indeterminate value to the pointer `temp` and using this pointer further in the loop invokes undefined behavior.

Moreover the condition in the loop

```
while(temp != NULL) // Untill temp get to end of the list
```

does not make a sense.

This declaration within the block scope of the loop

```
int i = 1; // Keep track on the position of the list
```

and the similar declaration in the function `printList`

```
int i = 1;
```

also do not make a sense.

You need to initialize exactly `n` nodes. So the loop should look like

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
    //...
}
```

Also you should free all the allocated memory when the list will not be needed any more.

Pay attention to that you allocated an array of nodes. Using your approach the program can look the following way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node 
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

// Printing the list
void printList( const struct node *ptr ) 
{
    for ( unsigned int i = 1; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next )
    {
        printf( "Value in Node %u : %d\n", i++, ptr->data );
    }
}

int main( void ) 
{
    unsigned int n = 0;
    struct node *head = NULL;

    printf( "Enter the size of linkedList : " );
    scanf( "%u", &n );

    head = malloc( n * sizeof( struct node ) );
    
    struct node *temp = head;
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "Enter the value in node %u : ", i + 1 );
        scanf( "%d", &temp->data );
        temp->next = i == n - 1 ? NULL : temp + 1;
        ++temp;
    }
    
    printList( head );
    
    free( head );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter the size of linkedList : 10
Enter the value in node 1 : 1
Enter the value in node 2 : 2
Enter the value in node 3 : 3
Enter the value in node 4 : 4
Enter the value in node 5 : 5
Enter the value in node 6 : 6
Enter the value in node 7 : 7
Enter the value in node 8 : 8
Enter the value in node 9 : 9
Enter the value in node 10 : 10
Value in Node 1 : 1
Value in Node 2 : 2
Value in Node 3 : 3
Value in Node 4 : 4
Value in Node 5 : 5
Value in Node 6 : 6
Value in Node 7 : 7
Value in Node 8 : 8
Value in Node 9 : 9
Value in Node 10 : 10
```

If you indeed want to organize data as a list instead of an array then the program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node 
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

// Printing the list
void printList( const struct node *ptr ) 
{
    for ( unsigned int i = 1; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next )
    {
        printf( "Value in Node %u : %d\n", i++, ptr->data );
    }
}

int main( void ) 
{
    unsigned int n = 0;
    struct node *head = NULL;

    printf( "Enter the size of linkedList : " );
    scanf( "%u", &n );

    struct node *temp;
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( i == 0 )
        {
            head = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
            temp = head;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->next = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        printf( "Enter the value in node %u : ", i + 1 );
        scanf( "%d", &temp->data );
        
        temp->next = NULL;
    }
    
    printList( head );
    
    while ( head != NULL )
    {
        temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free( temp );
    }       
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look as shown for the previous demonstrative program.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new node, you should allocate the next node and after that move the current node to the next one. Also, you should pay attention to the initial state (when size is 1). You should modify your code similar to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
  int data;
  struct node* next;
};

// Printing the list
void printList(struct node* ptr) {
  while (ptr != NULL) {
    int i = 1;
    printf("\n Value in Node %d : %d", i, ptr->data);
    ptr = ptr->next;
  }
}

int main() {
  int n;
  struct node* head;
  struct node* temp;
  printf("\n Enter the size of linkedList : ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  int i = 1;     // Keep track on the position of the list
  while (i <= n) // Untill temp get to end of the list
  {
    if (i == 1) {
      head = malloc(sizeof(struct node) * n);
      temp = head;
    } else {
      temp->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node) * n);
      temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n Enter the value in node %d : ", i);
    scanf("%d", &temp->data);
    ++i;
  }
  printList(head);
  return 0;
}
```

Also, you should free dynamically allocated memory at the end of the program to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Every time while allocating memory for node with `malloc(sizeof(struct node) * n)`. Does it only allocating memory of for single node? Or multiple nodes at a time ? What happens if do  --> `malloc(sizeof(struct node))` instead above one ?

Comment: A minor nitpick, but in `printList` you don't appear to increment `i` on each loop.